# Within or inside

Tags: word-choice

Which is correct?

There are one hundred thousand spies within the United States.
Or,
There are one hundred thousand spies inside the United States.

Answer (score 2):

***Generally***, in writing about numbers of things or people in countries, we say:

***in a country***

There are 10,000 widgets **in the country**.

Generally, **inside** is for a structure:

- There are three dogs inside the house and two outside.

Generally, within is more literary and a variation of in:

- Within any category, you will find many widgets.

So, I would not, personally, say: spies within the U.S. or inside the U.S.

Inside and within are also fine for borders: inside or within the country's borders. There are a lot of issues within or inside X's borders.

not: in the borders.

Answer (score 0):

The two words are almost as close to perfect synonyms as you will find. Idiomatically, sometimes only one is suitable for use in a certain situation - but even then, which one it is, or which situations have that sort of preference, depends on dialect.

You can use either. Worry not.

Answer (score -1):

Both are correct, primarily opinion based.

Within implies the container with a particular "part-of" word context. Inside implies a more natural way to specify only a "location" aspect.

How many states are within the US.

How many people are inside the US.