# How do we use "within" in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I have some difficulties with the use of the word “within” in essays. I know it means “inside” or “in”, but I don’t know in what contexts I should use this word.

“I am in my house” makes sense, but I know that “I am within my house” doesn’t.

Is “within” used for abstract things? “Within your heart”,  “within yourself”...

I’d like to have some examples and situations in which “within” can or can’t be used.

*not a native speaker**

Comment: You already know it. Yes, abstractions: within the parameters of the study. within is not used in contemporary English for physical things.

Comment: duplicate? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/203597/within-or-inside/203923#203923

Comment: @Lambie Has the UK become a non physical entity since Brexit? For orders within the UK, please enclose £2.50 for post and packing.

Comment: @Brad I said physical **thing**.  So, whatever you want. You want to call the UK, a physical "thing". Fine by me.

Answer (score 1):

Some Interesting Answers and comments; However

As an preposition, adverb It relates to

**inside or not further than an area or period of time:**

> Two thirds of Californians live within 15 miles of the coast.

> In 1992 cross-border controls within the EU were dismantled.

> For orders within the UK, please enclose £2.50 for post and packing.

> The resort lies within easy reach of (= not far from) the ski slopes.

**inside the limits of something,** for example the law or a set of rules, and allowed by it:

~>I was acting within the law (= legally).

---

Ref [How to use within](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/within.html)

Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/within)

Answer (score 0):

It conveys to something that *"comes together"*
(e.g. -strength that lies within.)

Also represents to something that *"standing in between"* and **not exceeding** - Like a time duration, or being part of two or more or subjects
(e.g. -within the allotted time. / -within those lines.)